# "git add -A" outputting nothing and not adding files

Tags: git, debugging

When I type `git add -A` or `git add .` from the root of my repository, nothing happens.  I mean nothing, like if I typed `echo >/dev/null`, just nothing.  If I type `git add`, I get `Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?`, which is what I'd expect.

With `git status`, a whole bunch of unstaged files, again what I expect.

The weird thing is that I'm able to solve this with `git commit -a ...etc`.  So, it's like I overwrote `git add -A` with an alias or there's something internally wrong somehow, but I don't even know where to start looking.  I don't know if it's worth knowing, but `git version 2.7.4`.

Everything other git command I've tried works as expected.

Edit:  I'm stupid.  I was thinking that it should still output something like you have no files to add, but it doesn't do that does it?  My bad.
It must be my `.gitignore`.  I will debug.

Comment: To clarify, but nothing happening, does that mean that the files were not staged, or that there was just not any output?

Comment: Does it also happen with other git repositories?

Comment: @JakeWorth - both.  No output, and files not staged.

Comment: What is the content of any `.gitignore` files?  Those would prevent some files from being added.

Comment: @JakeWorth - I'm stupid - see my edit.  Voted to close so curious people can see my edit, but it'll get closed

Comment: You can still answer your own question bellow when you find the answer. Instead of editing question, just answer yourself. Nothing wrong with that.